# What AD objects contain the Exchange 2007 attribute of LegacyExchangeDN?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2007, service-pack

Last night I went to upgrade our Exchange 2007 SP1 CU10 server to Service Pack 2, but almost immediatly I was presented with the below error:

```
Organization Preparation Failed

Error: "/o=RUSSOUND/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/ou=POWERHOG" is not valid for LegacyExchangeDN. Valid values are: Strings of the form "/o=<word>" optionally followed by "/ou=<word>" optionally followed by one or more instances of "/cn=<word>". Each "<word>" is at least one of uppercase and lowercase letters, digits, a space, and anything from the following group of characters: @!"%&'()*+,-.:<>?[]_{}|.

Elapsed Time: 00:04:41
```

I believe the error is telling me that in my case "ou=POWERHOG" should really be "cn=POWERHOG", since POWERHOG is the name of my exchange server. The problem I am having is that the error isn't clear about WHERE the LegacyExchangeDN that is causing the error is located at in AD.

Can someone help point me in the right direction for resolving this error so I can move forward with the SP2 upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check (using ADSIEdit or another LDAP editor) the value of the LegacyExchangeDN attribute for the object with the following LDAP path (assuming your Exchange Organization Name is "RUSSOUND") in the Configuration partition:

```
CN=POWERHOG,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=RUSSOUND,CN=Services,CN=Configuration
```

A.K.A.

```
Configuration\Services\RUSSOUND\Administrative Groups\Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)\Servers\POWERHOG
```

This is the LDAP object which represents your Exchange server, and its LegacyExchangeDN is what you need to look at.

Comment: This is the value I have here: /o=RUSSOUND/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=POWERHOG

As best I can tell, the only thing wrong here is the cn=Configuration doesn't belong.

Comment: @Russ, then something else is using that LegacyExchangeDN, and it of course isn't a valid one. Did you check the logs for the SP2 setup? Maybe you can find more details there.

Comment: I have no idea where the logs are being stored. The installer isn't telling me, ( or more likley I'm not seeing it tell me ).

Comment: I ended up running the "Best Practices tool" in exchange and it pointed me to this very same location. I believe the problem I am having is related to a legacy exchange server still in AD, but long since decommissioned.

Thanks.